# exjs update button menu values

Tags: extjs, drop-down-menu, setvalue

I have a button with 9 menu items, each 1 has a default value of "000000". These values are stored in an array.

The problem is only the default values are stored and not the updated values. How do I update the default colour with the colour chosen?

I thought that using setvalue would work but it does not :(

```
menu: [{
                text: "Main CPU Colour",
                menu: {
                    xtype  : "colormenu",
                    name   : "colourc",
                    value  : "000000",
                    cls    : "menubutton-class",
                    handler: function (obj, rgb) {
                        var colourmField = this.findField('colourc');
                        colourmField.setValue(rgb.toString());
                        alert(colourmField.getValue());
                    }
                }
            },{
```

Comment: Please remove that colourmField.setValue(rgb.toString()) line and check once.

Comment: I don't get how that will solve my problem. I left that handler so it might make clear what it was I wanted to achieve.